# Batch file/Powershell script to copy files from list.txt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need help on copying bunch of files from a source Volume folder to another volume folder. I want a script that copies the files from the given path listed on a .txt file. The script will copy the files including its directories. I have a code but it only copies the file and dump it all on one location not copying the directories.

Here's some script that I used. This scripts open up the filelist.txt "this has the list of path to the file". It only copies the file but not the entire directory.

```
$destination = "C:\copy_folder"
$textFileWithPaths = "C:\filelist.txt"

Get-Content $textFileWithPaths | % {
    # Create the destination folder path
    $NewFolder = Split-Path (Join-Path $destination $_) -Parent |
                 Split-Path -NoQualifier

    # Check if the path exsists - create if it doesn't exsist
    if (!(Test-Path $NewFolder)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewFolder -Force
    }
    # Copy the file to new location
    Copy-Item $_ $NewFolder -Force
}
```

I want to be able to copy the files with its complete directory. Not just the file itself. I have thousands of files so a manual copy and paste is not the best option.

Here's the filelist.txt file for your reference.

```
D:\Storage\Dapia Files\Dapia omgee\Fwd_ Google Cloud Directory Sync 
7_21_19 11_00 PM - SUCCESS (0 errors_ 0 warnings).msg
D:\Storage\Dapia Files\Dapia omgeeMy Town.JPEG
D:\Storage\Dapia Files\Dapia omgee\Veeam - RPV Report.xlsx
D:\Storage\My place.JPEG
D:\Storage\Networker Backup Process - Video Recording.mp4
D:\Storage\Veeam PTX Report.xlsx
D:\Storage\Winver Angie.JPG
```

Comment: you want to copy directories and its files to another location - that's it right ? is there any special reason you want to do via powershell ? what if this can be done on command prompt and not shell script ?

Comment: So for each file specified in your list you want to copy its parent directory with all its contents, right? so the specified file itself can be ignored in the list, true? why don't you specify a list of directories then? And how is your question linked to tag [tag:batch-file]?

Comment: shell or a cmd will work as long as it's a script.

Answer (score 0):

Change you `Copy-Item` call to:

```
Copy-Item "$_\*" $NewFolder -Force -Recurse
```

Based on the `Copy-Item` [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6) this should preserve the directory structure:

> Example 2: Copy the contents of a directory to another directory
>
> This command copies the entire contents of the "Logfiles" directory into the "Drawings" directory.
>
> Copy-Item "C:\Logfiles*" -Destination "C:\Drawings" -Recurse
>
> If the "LogFiles" directory contains files in subdirectories, those subdirectories are copied with their file trees intact. The Container parameter is set to "true" by default.
>
> This preserves the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ROBOCOPY` command, it's pretty good one.

My recommendation would be to add s, e, and z switches

```
 ROBOCOPY {source} {destination} /s /e /z

 /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
 /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
 /Z :: copy files in restartable mode.
```

[image]

Comment: Surely you would use either `/E` or `/S`, not both!

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I already found the script for this. It was a powershell. Thanks for your help.